# Simple Anylogic Mat Handling conveyor not showing my custom Material Item Type box

Tags: anylogic

I am a beginner and I have created a simple "source-queue-convey-sink" circuit. The dimensions of the associated conveyor are about 4 meters long. I have created a custom MaterialItemType of a box about .5 meters square.
When I run it I can see the numbers of agents (boxes) rising as they go through the system and can see the conveyor turning.. but my boxes are not showing on the conveyor. Any thoughts an what might be up.

Below is the box "Material Type"  which is my agent being moved on the conveyor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR3SN.png)

and below is the model with property focus on the convey block.

I feel it might have to do with the dimensions.. I have the scale set to 100 pixels to 1 meter and this may be unusual perhaps?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Er9f.png)

Finally this is the runtime and if viewed dynamically you would see that the box count is going up and the conveyor is turning but the boxes are not showing on the conveyor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO3b6.png)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the model and also where the boxes are not visible.

Comment: On your screenshot there are 0 boxes actively on the conveyor, so there should not be any on the conveyor at the time of the screenshot. Can you capture a screenshot with the convey block having a "1" on top it in the counter. This will indicate that it is actively conveying an object and then you should see it in the animation. (Maybe your speed is just way too fast?)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you did not click the "Show presentation" button in the properties of the agent of the boxes.

Normally, AnyLogic creates the presentation for you but sometimes, you delete it and need to re-include it with this button, as below. You can find that by clicking on an agent population of your boxes.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply Benjamin.. much appreciated. My agent is a "Material Item" which is I guess a more expanded version of a simple agent type. It doesn't seem to have the "Show Presentation" property you refer to above?

Comment: is your Source creating FullTote agents?